# Why jshint alerts Read only on lastSelectedRow

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

Code below pasted to jshint.com site causes error

`Read only`

at line

lastSelectedRow = 1;

Why this error occurs and how to fix it?
jslint does not thow this error.

```
/*global lastSelectedRow */
function main() {
  lastSelectedRow = 1;
  return 'Hello, World!';
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Read only" error occurs when you assign a value to a built-in native object or a global variable. In your code since you mention in the comments that lastSelectedRow is a global variable, JSHint raises this error to highlight that there is a chance for potential data loss.

This error does not mean that your code will not work correctly, but there is a chance it might break third party scripts.

Refer http://jslinterrors.com/read-only for more information.

I do not understand your use case from the code you gave. To fix it, you can change the variable name inside the function scope and avoid re-assignment to the global variable.

```
/*global lastSelectedRow */
function main() {
  var aa = lastSelectedRow;
  return aa.toString() + 'Hello, World!';
}

main();
```

Comment: `lastSelectedRow` is my global variable name. It is not built-in name. I need to assign value to it as shown in my code. Code in answer does not assign a value to lastSelectedRow . So this is not answer. Is this jshint bug ?

Comment: This is not a bug in jshint. It raises that error when you assign value to a global variable and it is the chosen behavior. You could ignore this error if you want to do it anyway.